# Update or Insert rows from XML in SQL table using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I have an XML file how came from a machine with many parameters. Now i would like to store this parameters in my SQL Database. All times when i import a new XML file i need to check if the ID allready exist in my table what meens i need to Update this row or if not exist it need to insert a new row.

My first step after i read the xml file is to create a Temp SQL table where i put all the data from my XML file.

After this step i will merge the TempTable to the OriginalTable with SQL like (IF EXIST ID FROM dbo._TOOL IN dbo.TOOL UPDATE dbo.TOOL ELSE INSERT)

Is there a other way tho merge an SQL Table whith dynamic generatet column names and values and not with hardcoded values?

```
            string mergeSql = "merge into Tool as Target " +
                              "using _Tool as Source " +
                              "on " +
                              "Target.ID=Source.ID " +
                              "when matched then " +
                              "update set Target.Obj=Source.Obj " +
                              "when not matched then " +
                              "insert (Obj,.....,Step) values (Source.Obj,....,Source.Step);";
```

Or is this the wrong way to do somthing like this?

Comment: Are you storing XML in the database, or shredding the XML document into distinct tables / columns?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Im storing the XML document in one table, the only one diference i had is that i have an auto increment column for my ID in my SQL Server table